# ASP.NET MVC3 Html.EditorFor() problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i try to bind data to model with Html.EditorFor() helper and submit, but model come to controller is null.

Here is code of model:

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [LocalizedRequired]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [LocalizedRequired]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("Remember Me")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

this is cshtml:

```
@model Models.LogOnModel
{
    View.Title = "Log On";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName);
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password);
    <input type="submit" value="LogOn" />
}
```

and html code is generate like this:

```
<input id="UserName_UserName" name="UserName.UserName" type="text" value="qwerty" />
<input id="Password_Password" name="Password.Password" type="password" />
```

it seems like error in html-generated code, it should be id="someid" value="somevalue", but not id="someid_someid" value="somevalue.somevalue"

Comment: Did you create your own Editor template? If so, could you post that code?

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` with `EditorFor` worked fine for me.  My id and name attributes were just "Password" like I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks! yes, it was problem in editor template:

```
<div class="textinput">@Html.TextBox(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, Model)</div>
```

i solve it like this:

```
<div class="textinput">@Html.TextBox(String.Empty)</div>
```

is it a good solution?

Comment: `<div class="textinput">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)</div>` should work for you.

Comment: yes, it works! thanks! can you explain me difference between my solution and yours?

Comment: Why do you need an editor template for a simple string field?

And, why do you feel necessary to use LocalizedRequired and LocalizedDisplayName instead of Required and DisplayName?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're just using textboxes you could always use the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName);
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password);
   <input type="submit" value="LogOn" />
}
```

Otherwise it might depend on custom templates that you've created.

Answer (score 2):

Hi You Can Solve it by just putting @type directive just like this:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@type="password" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password);
   <input type="submit" value="LogOn" />
}
```